Low quality answers to "almost" off-topic questions
Recently, I have noticed a rather high frequency of low quality answers being flagged in the review queue. I am unsure if the answers are automatically flagged by the community due to its length, but I feel most of the answers are valid answers. They are just concise and to-the-point. Then, I start to wonder if its the question itself that asks for a fairly simple answer.
Should there be a guideline for asking questions, particularly translation/meaning related questions, that encourages comprehensive, open-ended, brain-picking answers? Or is it acceptable to have fairly simple answers?

I'm new to this site, and below is my own opinion:
If the answer is concise and precise, accept it. Answers are not the problem, the questions are. 
